# SignalR Broadcast from Controller Not Invoking Client Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm using Signalr 1.1 and I'm trying a simple project involving updating a progress bar.  I've read other people having similar issues but non seem to really help.  I'm thinking I may have lost my mind.

I set up a hub

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace VBS_MVC.Hubs
{
    public class ProgressBarHub : Hub
    {
        public void CheckSend()
        {
            Clients.All.updateProgressBar();
        }
    }
}
```

Which, I don't really need for this, but I have it set up for testing.

My controller looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProgressBarTest(string SignalRConnectionId)
        {
            // Get the value of the hidden from the request
            string currentClientConnectionId = SignalRConnectionId;

            // Get the hub context
            Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext myHubContext = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hubs.ProgressBarHub>();

            // Resolve a the client that corresponds to the current request
            dynamic currentClient = myHubContext.Clients.Client(currentClientConnectionId);

            currentClient.updateProgressBar();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            myHubContext.Clients.Client(currentClientConnectionId).updateProgressBar();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

            myHubContext.Clients.All.updateProgressBar();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);


            return View();
        }
```

and on my client:

```
<h2>ProgressBarTest</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<input type="hidden" id="mySignalRConnectionIdHidden" name="SignalRConnectionId" />
 <input type="submit" />
}

<button class="signalr">Test Send</button>

<div id="counter">
Counter
</div>

 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            var progress = $.connection.progressBarHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            progress.client.updateProgressBar = function () {
                console.log('test');
            };

            $('.signalr').click(function () {
                progress.server.checkSend();
            });

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#mySignalRConnectionIdHidden").val($.connection.hub.id);
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });


    </script>
```

The connectionId looks like its making it into the post just fine, and if I click on the button I have outside of the form (it talks directly to the hub) that works fine.  As you can see I'm trying to broadcast to the client in different ways but nothing seems to work.  What am I missing?

Comment: add this line: `$.connection.hub.logging = true;` to your javascript and check if it's logging anything in the console.

Comment: Thanks, I was working with that last night.  One common error I'm receiving is SignalR: Keep alive has been missed, connection may be dead/slow. libs:45.  This seems to be related to a bug with Chrome and it does work fine in FF and IE.  So there's that.  I'm currently trying to find a workaround for that

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
Clients.All.updateProgressBar();
```

To:

```
Clients.All.UpdateProgressBar();
```

I believe the dynamic method names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your hub class:

```
[HubName("progressBarHub")]
```

The hub name is case sensitive and you are calling it with a lowercase 'p' in your javascript.

Comment: This isn't this issue.  The client wants the hub name in camel case.  Also, I can talk freely through the hub, the issue arises when i attempt to invoke the client side method from the controller using the IHubContext.  For good measure, I attempted to add the Hubname and the behavoir hasn't changed